# jquery send action on focus and view lines of text

Tags: ajax, jquery

ie. we have page with many lines of text

```
<div class="textline" id=line1>text line or line with image no reason</div>
<div class="textline" id=line2>text line or line with image  no reason</div>
<div class="textline" id=line500>text line or line with image  no reason</div>
```

How to get last **really visible lineID on the screen of visitor(not on whole page)** and send this ID to server with jquery? 
1) first time send - when page get focused more then 5 seconds (really viewed), need to send last visible lineID from the screen of visitor.
2) when page scrolled down need to send last visible line (think with some little timeout)

Is it possible with jquery? Any examples?

Comment: not sure how, but just noting you should also capture the resize event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the last element from a list of `.textline` elements.

**Example:**

```
$(".textline").last();
```

Or, if you want to select the last element visible on the *screen in the viewport*, you'll have to do something a lot more complex, like this:

```
$(".textline").each(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

    if(offset <= window.innerHeight - $(this).height){
        // it's the last visible line, do something with it. 
        // you can put a call to your server containing the 
        // line's current text with something like this:
        // var curText = $(this).val();
    }
}
```

Comment: On the second answer, I don't see where you find that the current line is the last visible line, looks like all visible lines would run the commented section

Answer (score 0):

this selects last `.textline`:

```
$('.textline').last().text()
```